# Binomial distribution where probability parameter is also a distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Suppose I have $J \sim$ Bin$(25, P)$, but instead of having fixed $P$, I have a known PDF for continuous $P$, given by $f_{P}(p)$. How would I find $\mathbb{E}[J]$, given this to be the case?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ParameterMixtureDistribution`(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParameterMixtureDistribution.html)

For example:

```
pmd = ParameterMixtureDistribution[BinomialDistribution[25, p], 
   p \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[q, b]];
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] pmd]
```

yields: (25 q)/(b + q)

Comment: You could also use `Mean[pmd]`

Comment: @BobHanlon yes would have been shorter. Thank you.